# How to scroll to the last element <li> in a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an  element in my page and I am using a Jquery Plugin to scroll to the last `<li>` in the page whenever a new `<li>` is added but it is not working. The plugin link is [scrollTo Plugin](http://lions-mark.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

```
<ol class"chat">
  <li>chat 1</li>
  <li>chat 2</li>
  <li>chat 3</li>
  <li>chat 4</li>
  <li>chat 5</li>
  <li>chat 6</li>
</ol>
```

my code is: `$('.chat').scrollTo('*:last', 0);`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
$('.chat').scrollTo('*:last', 0);
```

Try(You want last `li` so instead of `*` use `li`)

```
$('.chat').scrollTo('li:last', 0);
```

OR (I don't think there is any need of 0),So try this :-

```
$('.chat').scrollTo('li:last');
```

Comment: Tried this before and still did not scroll

Comment: @BlackPearl...make sure that you have included jquery file in your page and check for any console errors..

Comment: checked console, and no error and all files are included.

Comment: @BlackPearl...instead of `$('.chat').scrollTo('li:last');` try `$('body').scrollTo('li:last');`

Comment: same thing, dunno if it has issues with JQuery Mobile

Comment: Thanks but till couldn't fix it with it

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem using the code below without the plugin.

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height()-$(window).height() },1000);
```